# How can I get a Github actions job to use a different runner if the first runner is already busy or unavailable

Tags: github-actions

In this example Github workflow, I would like to use a different runner if the first runner is already maxed out or no longer available. This would allow me to set a monthly budget for high performance build runners and then enterprise credit for standard Github hosted runners. Or in the case of self hosted runner, switch to Github hosted runners if the self hosted runners become unavailable. How would I do this?

I have tried:

```yaml
name: Build application

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build application
    runs-on:
      - ubuntu-latest-large  # higher performance runner
      - ubuntu-latest        # standard runner
  steps:
     # ...
```

The code above results in `and` rather than `or` condition:

```bash
Requested labels: ubuntu-latest-large, ubuntu-latest
Job defined at: org/project/.github/workflows/ci-build.yml@refs/pull/123/merge
Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...
```

Comment: I found this discussion: "[Feature Request: Automatically switch to Github runner if self hosted runner is not available](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/20019)"

Comment: I even tried "[runs-on support conditional variable](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/70323)"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

One way I have tackled a similar scenario is by using the GitHub API. For me, I wanted to run on a GitHub runner only if all my self-hosted runners were already consumed (our on-prem runners are faster, but if they get bottlenecked by pure quantity of workflows, it is faster to go to a GitHub hosted runner until they free up more).

An existing action for this is here if you want a sample: https://github.com/BenjaminMichaelis/get-soonest-available-runner/blob/main/action.yml

You should be able to follow this very similarly in order to create the action you want. I am happy to try to provide more input on your specific scenario if you have further questions as right now there are some specifics with your scenario that are difficult to design for.